# Ensure HyperV VM uses only Private Network using GPO

Tags: group-policy, hyper-v

Developers in my organization would like to host development virtual machines on their workstations.
They want full control on the VM.

It would be against company policy to allow such machines to access company's network.

Is there a way to force HyperV host to use only Private Networks, so Security would allow such VMs?
For example using GPOs?

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this at the network level, rather than with GPOs, along with some guidance to your developers.  I prefer this method, instead of feeding workstations with multiple VLANs on their network lines.

General steps would be:

- The switch ports for workstations would be configured to only allow a single MAC per switchport.
- The switch ports would have MAC stickiness enabled and set for an appropriately long time, so that the allowed MAC is the one that the computer first presents on boot.
- Inform your developers of this setup, with instructions to help them configure the private HyperV virtualized network on their machine so that it doesn't seek to access outside resources.

If you have Cisco Catalyst equipment for the MAC-related portions of my recommendation, you'd do these by:

1. Copy the default cisco-desktop Smartport Macro to [a new one](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/12-2/25sg/configuration/guide/conf/macro.html), call it something like lockdown-desktop.  When creating the new macro, add "[switchport port-security mac-address sticky](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst4500/12-2/20ewa/configuration/guide/conf/port_sec.html)" to it.
2. Apply the macro to your developers' switchports.